# Команда repo для убунту

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

Как мне установить данную команду через apt-get (в каком пакете она есть)? Команда `repo`, которая нужна для работы с `git`.

Comment: сам пакет git пробовал ставить?

Answer (score 1):

Я не спец по git'у. Но вроде в git такой команды, как repo нет. Есть такая [надстройка](http://code.google.com/p/git-repo/) (скрип по сути) над git. Чтобы ее пользоваться, надо ее просто скачать

```
curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/googlesource/git-repo/repo > ~/bin/repo
chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
```